# Can I stub different responses for subsequent calls to the same endpoint with Nocilla?

Tags: swift, xctest, nocilla

I want to do something like this:

```
stubRequest("GET", "http://localhost:8000/api/foo").andReturn(401)
stubRequest("GET", "http://localhost:8000/api/foo").andReturn(200)

let result = service.myServiceCall()

XCTAssertEqual(result, "My Result")
```

... so that the first call to `/api/foo` in my test gets a 401 response and the second call gets a 200. Is this possible with Nocilla?

*Note that both these calls happen inside `myServiceCall()` so I can't reset the Nocilla stubs in the middle.*

Comment: This is an older question but I have the same problem